# How to address to administrative people

Tags: spoken-english, parts-of-speech

My question is about how to address to people but let me explain the situation.

Tomorrow a visiting professor is giving a talk in our school. I am a chair in his speech. This is my first time to be a chair. I have found some tips from YouTube how to open the ceremony and how to introduce the presenter but unfortunately I have no idea how to address our dean, deputy dean etc and also I have no idea what should I say before singing the National Anthem and University Anthem.

Could someone advice me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When introducing them for the first time, call a professor named John Smith "Professor John Smith." Call a dean named John Smith "Dean John Smith." Call a deputy dean named John Smith "Deputy Dean John Smith." Subsequent to introducing them for the first time, call the professor "Professor Smith." Call both the dean and the deputy dean "Dean Smith."

Before singing the National Anthem, say "I will now sing the National Anthem" or "please join me in singing the National Anthem," depending on whether you are inviting everyone to sing it with you (it is more usual to invite everyone to sing it). Do the same with the university anthem.

Comment: Is it OK if I use "Her Excellency..." do the dean

Comment: @user480970 I wouldn't. I think it would sound pretentious. Just "I would like to introduce Dean So-and-so," with perhaps the addition of "the dean of the whichever school." (My father was a law professor at Notre Dame for 57 years, and I would just call his dean "Dean Newton." If I ran into her, I'd just say "Hi Dean" in the same way as I might say "Hi Doctor" to a doctor.)